# How to call a package on ORACLE APEX using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle-apex

I'm pretty new to Oracle APEX, and I'm trying to figure out how to call a package using a JavaScript action in a Dynamic Action (DA). I want to execute a package in Oracle APEX using JavaScript, but I'm not quite sure where to start. Can you help me with the steps involved in setting this up? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use apex.server.process or create a dynamic action of type "execute server-side code". However, you state "I'm pretty new to apex" and you ask for something relatively uncommon. Can you explain in detail what the problem is you're trying to solve ? There might be a much easier way to do it in APEX.